# How to convert string from textbox into a number using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox with input value of **20,466,000.00** . I want to return only the value of 20466000 without a comma and a decimal point. I tried the following :

```
// Get value
var nca_balance = $("#nca-balance").text();
var nca_amount = parseInt(nca_balance.replace(",", ""),10);

alert(nca_amount);
```

But it only returns the value of **20466** ? Why ? My expected result must be 20466000. Please help with my code. Thanks

Comment: You retrieve the value of an `<input>` with `.val()`, not `.text()`; if that really were what your code looked like the `.text()` call would have returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

How about this one:

```
parseInt("20,466,000.00".replace(/,/g, ""), 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because replace is replacing the first comma by default use `g` as global option in replace regular expression `/,/g` like,

```
var nca_balance = $("#nca-balance").text();
var nca_amount = parseInt(nca_balance.replace(/,/g, ""),10);
alert(nca_amount);
```

```js
    var nca_balance = $("#nca-balance").text();
    var nca_amount = parseInt(nca_balance.replace(/,/g, ""), 10);
    alert(nca_amount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="nca-balance">20,466,000.00<span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `regular expression` instead of `replace` function because replace function will replace only first matching character.

```js
nca_balance = "20,466,000.00";
var nca_amount = parseInt(nca_balance.replace(/,/g, ''));
alert(nca_amount);
```

Regular expression `/,/g` will replace all comma with your provided character globally.